# Getting an specific day before current date

Tags: javascript, date

How do I get the latest date from a base day of month, in JavaScript.

I could not find this anywhere, so let me explain in an example:

Today is Oct 2nd, as my base day is 5, I need to somehow retrieve the date September 5th. The date should be in the past, that means that if the current date is Oct 6th, I need to return Oct 5th, if Nov 6th, then Nov 5th, if Nov 23rd, then Nov 5th, and so on.

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: IF currentday >= baseday THEN <use base day of same month> ELSE <subtract one from the month and use the base day of that month, accounting for january rolling back to december>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` constructor is smart enough to roll over to previous months if given "impossible" dates like a month of -1. Note that months in JavaScript dates are zero-based, so 0 is January, 11 is December, etc.

```js
function getLastBaseDate(date, base) {
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - (date.getDate() >= base ? 0 : 1), base);
}

console.log(getLastBaseDate(new Date(2020, 9, 5), 5).toISOString());   // 2020-10-05
console.log(getLastBaseDate(new Date(2020, 9, 4), 5).toISOString());   // 2020-09-05
console.log(getLastBaseDate(new Date(2020, 0, 1), 5).toISOString());   // 2019-12-05
console.log(getLastBaseDate(new Date(2020, 11, 6), 5).toISOString());  // 2020-12-05
```

Comment: Thanks.. All of the questions were very helpful, I picked this one because it was the one that spent the least amount of lines. I've just made a tiny modification, to keep the hh:mm:ss  -> if (date.getDate() <= base) {
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
    }
date.setDate(base);

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand correctly

The `stringDate` param is optional so you test `10/6/20`.

The `${currentMonth + 1}` is because months are 0 indexed. When you pass them back to the Date constructor they are interpreted at face value `9 = Sept`.

```
function getPastDate(stringDate) {
    const currentDate = stringDate ? new Date(stringDate) : new Date();
    const currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
    const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth(); // 9 for Oct Months are 0 indexed
    const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    const baseDay = 5;
    console.log(currentDay, currentMonth, currentYear)
    if (currentDay > baseDay) {
        return new Date(`${currentMonth + 1}/${baseDay}/${currentYear}`);
    }

    return new Date(`${currentMonth}/${baseDay}/${currentYear}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can do what you requested. It has no error checking, so it gives funky results when base is less than 1 or more than the amount of days in the current or previous month.

```
let base = 5;
let date = new Date()
let today = date.getDate();
if (today >= base) {
    console.log(date.toString());
} else {
    let d = date.getMonth()
    date.setMonth(d-1);
  date.setDate(base)
  console.log(date.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that i understant what exactly want. this could be a solution:

```
Solution = (base, dd = 0, mm = 0) => {
  let months = [
    ["January", 31],
    ["February", 29],
    ["March", 31],
    ["April", 30],
    ["May", 31],
    ["June", 30],
    ["July", 31],
    ["August", 31],
    ["September", 30],
    ["October", 31],
    ["November", 30],
    ["December", 31],
  ];
  let d = 0;
  let m = 0;
  if (dd === 0 && mm === 0) {
    day = new Date();
    d == day.getDate();
    m = day.getMonth();
  } else if (validDay(dd, mm, months)) {
    d = dd;
    m = mm - 1;
  } else {
    return "invalid date";
  }
  if (d <= base) {
    base = base >= 10 ? base : "0" + base;
    return base + " " + months[m - 1][0];
  } else {
    base = base >= 10 ? base : "0" + base;
    return base + " " + months[m][0];
  }
};
validDay = (day, month, months) => {
  if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
    if (day >= 1 && day <= months[month - 1][1]) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

If you don't set the mm and dd parameters, it just takes the day of today.
The solution does not care if the year is leap or not, but it is easy to check this.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

You would first have to roll-back the month if the date you are setting is greater than the current date.

After you have done that, you can set the date.

```js
const dates = [
  { in: '2020-10-05T00:00:00Z', out: '2020-10-05T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { in: '2020-10-06T00:00:00Z', out: '2020-10-05T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { in: '2020-11-06T00:00:00Z', out: '2020-11-05T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { in: '2020-11-23T00:00:00Z', out: '2020-11-05T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { in: '2020-11-04T00:00:00Z', out: '2020-10-05T00:00:00.000Z' },
  { in: '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z', out: '2019-12-05T00:00:00.000Z' }
],
  dayOfMonth = 5;

/**
 *  Takes a UTC date modifies the day of month.
 *  @param {Date} dateObj
 *  @param {int} dayOfMonth
 *  @return Returns a past date for the provided dateObj
 */
const toBaseDate = (dateObj, dayOfMonth) => {
  const [ date, month ] = [ dateObj.getUTCDate(), dateObj.getUTCMonth() ];
  if (date === dayOfMonth) return dateObj;
  if (date < dayOfMonth) dateObj.setUTCMonth(month - 1);
  dateObj.setUTCDate(dayOfMonth);
  return dateObj;
}

console.log(dates.every(dateString => {
  const date = new Date(dateString.in);
  const baseDate = toBaseDate(date, dayOfMonth);
  return baseDate.toISOString() === dateString.out;
}) ? 'pass' : 'fail');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```